# How to manage relationships in the Umbraco CMS?

Tags: umbraco, relationship, relation

I have relationships between some pages on my multilingual website.

The question is:

1. How to delete a relationship (note - I don't want to delete the relation type, just one of the relationship) in the CMS? (Can't see any option) Can this be done only programmatically?
2. How to add a relation in the CMS? Is there any way to add a relationship apart of when I copy a node?
3. I have added new custom relation type in the CMS (in Developer > Relation Types) and I can't see an option to add this type of relation between two nodes? Can this be done only programmatically?

Thanks

Comment: Both, I have 2 websites one with Umbraco 6 another with 7

Answer (score 4):

You can install a package for v6 such as Multipicker Relations - http://ucomponents.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MultiPickerRelations&referringTitle=DataTypes

For v7 this allows editing: http://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/umbraco-relation-editor

Or this may work: http://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/nupickers

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the documentation for the RelationService: http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Management-v6/Services/RelationService

And here's an example of using the RelationService: https://github.com/sitereactor/Umbraco-Lunch-App/blob/master/Chainbox.FoodApp/Controllers/Api/FoodRelationController.cs

Comment: Thank you. I know these pages. But my question was about how to manage relationships in the CMS not from code behind

Comment: You can't do it from the backoffice, only through code.

Comment: That's what I needed to confirm. Thanks @sebastiaan!